# Serverless resource creation for public S3 bucket for uploading public assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create a S3 bucket using serverless framework with the following objectives

1. The bucket is going to hold public assets. Mainly the application users are going to upload their logos and images in the bucket and the image url can be directly shared with the internet (since its only images and logos)
2. Write access is only via our rest api on lambda function (exposed using api gateway)
3. I need the ability to publicly access the asset using the object url.

So far my resource creation template looks like this:

```
LogoPublicS3Bucket: 
  Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket" 
  Properties: 
    AccessControl: PublicRead 
    BucketName: portal-settings-${self:custom.stage}-public-bucket
    CorsConfiguration: 
      CorsRules: 
        - AllowedMethods: 
            - GET 
            - HEAD 
          AllowedOrigins: 
            - "*"
          AllowedHeaders:
            - "*"
    VersioningConfiguration: 
      Status: Enabled
LogoPublicS3BucketPolicy: 
  Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy' 
  Properties: 
    PolicyDocument: 
      Statement: 
        - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects 
          Effect: Allow 
          Principal: '*' 
          Action: 
            - 's3:GetObject' 
          Resource: arn:aws:s3:::portal-settings-${self:custom.stage}-public-bucket/* 
    Bucket: 
      Ref: LogoPublicS3Bucket
LogoPublicS3SecureTransportPolicy:
  Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    Bucket:
      Ref: LogoPublicS3Bucket
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Deny"
          Action:
            - "s3:*"
          Principal: '*'
          Resource:
            - 'Fn::Join':
              - ''
              - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
                - Ref: LogoPublicS3Bucket
                - /*
          Condition:
            Bool:
              'aws:SecureTransport': false
```

The issue is that the above serverless file is not working. Upload to my S3 bucket via aws-sdk gives me access denied + if I upload a file via console then the object url is not public

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The above serverless file is not working. Upload to my S3 bucket via aws-sdk gives me access denied + if I upload a file via console then the object url is not public

Comment: When you upload to the S3 bucket via the AWS SDK, you will need to provide AWS credentials for your code to access S3. How are you providing these credentials to your code, and what permissions are associated with those credentials?

Comment: I tried deploying your template, but it was upset about having 2 Bucket Policies for the same bucket. You should combine those policies by specifying two Statements in the one Bucket Policy.